# How do i connect HmailServer to MySQL( in WAMP)?

Tags: mysql, wamp, hmail-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYUwA.png)I'm try to install hmailserver in combination with wamp/mysql.

I get an errormessage, hmailserver recommends to copy a file manually.

copypaste:

> Error:
>   The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.
>   hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.
>   The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.
>   Path: H:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll.

I don't see MySql in the service (Step 5 in the "HmailServer Database Step up -Step 5 of 7). And wampapache doesn't work either.
Thank you for the help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhcnF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I go into "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\lib" right click "libmysql.dll" next press copy. I go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin" and paste the copied file into it

Answer (score 0):

The MYSQL Server service is called `wampmysqld` or if you have the 64bit WAMPServer `wampmysqld64`

However I would suggest that you take the other option and use the SQLServer database with hmailserver.

If you use MySQL which I admit seems like the most obvious option, then every time you ADDON another MySQLServer version to WAMPServer you will have to migrate the hmailserver database over to the new MySQL, and like me forget to do so.

If you use the built in SQLServer database with hmailserver, you can basically forget about hmailserver whenever you change something in WAMPServer's MySQLServer versions.

Comment: I have tried what you said and the wampmysql doesn't work  ( See the question edited).

Comment: "_If you use MySQL which I admit seems like the most obvious option, then every time you ADDON another MySQLServer version to WAMPServer you will have to migrate the hmailserver database over to the new MySQL, and like me forget to do so_ " -                                  
                                                                                                           
            Can you kindly explain to me how you do so? and if I choose the option of "Microsoft SQL Server" will that connect to the database i made?

Comment: No the idea is you use SQLServer for hMailer and MySQL for all your projects,

Answer (score 0):

Regarding hMailServer and MySQL 8.x

It doesn't matter if you run a 32-Bit or 64-Bit MySQL Server on the same Windows
Machine or on a Remote server (regardless which OS) as long as you have the required libmysql.dll file in hMailServer /bin folder or a at your PATH Environment variable.

Regarding MySQL 8.x:
MySQL 8.x enables per default its new API API which is incompatible with 
all hMailServer versions. You need to configure MySQL 8.x in mixed mode which allows
5.7.x MySQL Clients to connect to make it work with hMailServer. You also can use
a MySQL 5.7.x Release without any configuration to make it work out of the box.
For more info see: https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=33819